# MQTT Subscriber Missing messages

Tags: python, mqtt

I am trying to send messages from one client to another using MQTT, both are publishers and subscribers. In the case of the first client, is a Raspberry that runs 4 process that are 4 executions of the program, on the other side, a server that must receive all the messages that the 4 processes are publishing.

The subscriber part:

```
mqttc = paho.Client()                                       # mqttc object
# assign on_connect func
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
# assign on_message func
mqttc.on_message = on_message
#mqttc.on_log = on_log

mqttc.tls_set(caPath, certfile=certPath, keyfile=keyPath, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
              tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, ciphers=None)  # pass parameters

# connect to aws server
mqttc.connect(awshost, awsport, keepalive=60)

### *Till here* ###

sleep(3)
mqttc.loop_start()                                          # Start the loop
ethName = getEthName()
ethMAC = getMAC(ethName)
macIdStr = ethMAC
mqttc.subscribe("home/AWS1", 1)
mqttc.subscribe("home/AWS2", 1)

while 1 == 1:
    if connflag == True:
        p = 1  # line that does nothing only waits

    else:
        print("waiting for connection...")
```

The issue is that in the server I'm only getting the messages of the first 2 clients. Also, the 4 clients send the messages almost at the same time and I do not know if this is a problem.

Comment: What is the `sleep(3)` for? Also you should probably mode the `mqttc.subscribe()` calls to inside the `on_connect()` callback.

Comment: @hardillb Hey! I've seen you commenting on other MQTT posts. I wonder if waiting this way is the best way for a publisher-subscriber program or maybe you think there is a better way to do it. The sleep is just to ensure that the connection has already been made and I can try to put the mqttc.subscribe inside the on_connect().

Comment: The sleep is pointless, use the `on_connect()` to know when the connection has completed, that is explicitly what it's for, especially as you are not starting the loop until after it.

Comment: @hardillb Thank you!!! and besides that, there's a better way to wait in a subscriber-publisher program?

Comment: These is not enough code in the question to say

Comment: Are you auto-generating MQTT Client IDs?  If you have 4 Publishers on one machine, then you can't use things like Hostname or MAC address as the ClientID...the MQTT Broker will only let in one connection per ClientID.  What does your Broker logfile say?